# How can I get a type safe route to a static dir (not a static file)?

Tags: haskell, yesod

In a shakespearean template, I need to get the route to a static dir. How can I achieve that?

```
@{StaticR images_myimage_png}  <-- works
@{StaticR images}              <-- does not work
@{StaticR images_}             <-- does not work either
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do that, but I don't understand why  would someone need to render URL to a directory. It doesn't make much sense as that directory would be resolved to some file (e.g.index.html), and therefore it's not safe as you don't know what it would resolve to. My guess is that you want to use it for something non-web. Could you tell why do you need that?

Comment: I need the absolute route to the "images" dir, which is in my "static" dir (ie "/static/images/"). That's for a js library which need to know where some images are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need to use the `StaticRoute` constructor directly. The identifier generation only generates identifiers for files, not directories, since that's normally what people want (as @zudov explains). You should be able to do something like:

```
@{StaticR $ StaticRoute ["images"] []}
```